# Any software that converts text to speech and sends speech via a microphone?

Tags: python, microphone, text

I'm in a strange predicament right now. I'm taking a virtual class through work and at work in my cubicle. I'd like to be able to quietly do this but sometimes I have to speak into the microphone instead of talking in the chat. I'd like to just type into a program, have the program convert it into speech, and then send that speech into a microphone so I can remain silent and still communicate effectively with my instructor.

If there is any software or even a Python library, I'd love to use it or build it myself.

Thank you,

Answer (score 3):

Two steps to this solution;

1. Text to speech: There are a number of approaches you can take to best solve your particular need: [Ubuntu Community Text to Speech](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/TextToSpeech). Pick the one you find to be preferable.
2. Redirect the audio out to the microphone input: Here is one solution that fully [redirects the audio out to the microphone input](http://www.kirsle.net/blog/kirsle/redirect-audio-out-to-mic-in--linux-).

I have not prototyped this yet, but this should set you firmly on the right path. Let us know of your progress.

Answer (score 1):

## **Gespeaker**

[image: Install via the software center]

It is a nice application that can open any `.txt` file and read:

Additional ***Language packs*** and ***Tones*** are available.

It can also **record** the Speech.

[image]

Can installed with [**Software Center**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gespeaker/) Or with:

```
sudo apt-get install gespeaker espeaker
```